# Pandas counting occurrence of list contained in column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have this Pandas DataFrame that has a column with lists:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'m': [[1,2,3], [5,3,2], [2,5], [3,8,1], [9], [2,6,3]]})
>>> df
           m
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [5, 3, 2]
2     [2, 5]
3  [3, 8, 1]
4        [9]
5  [2, 6, 3]
```

I want to count the number of times a list `v = [2, 3]` is contained in the lists of the DataFrame. So in this example the correct answer would be `3`. Now this is just an example, in my actual data the `df['m']` can contain more than 9 million rows and the lists are actually lists of strings with up to about 20 elements. Some more details if it matters: The elements of `v` contain no duplicates and neither do the lists of `m`, so they can be sets instead of lists.

The first iteration of my program iterated over each row and checked `all(e in data['m'][i] for e in v)` and if that's True, I increment a counter. But as addressed in many SO questions and blog posts, iterating over the rows of a DataFrame is slow and can be done much faster.

So for my next iteration I added a column to the DataFrame that contains a copy of the list `v`:

```
>>> df['V'] = [[2, 3]] * len(df)
>>> df
        V          m
0  [2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]
1  [2, 3]  [5, 3, 2]
2  [2, 3]     [2, 5]
3  [2, 3]  [3, 8, 1]
4  [2, 3]        [9]
5  [2, 3]  [2, 6, 3]
```

and a helper function that simply returns the containment boolean like I did before:

```
def all_helper(l1, l2):
    return all(v in l1 for v in l2)
```

which I can then use with `np.vectorize` to add a column with the boolean value:

```
df['bool'] = np.vectorize(all_helper)(df['m'], df['V'])
```

And lastly, calculate the sum of these booleans with a simple `df['bool'].sum()`

I also tried to use `.apply()`:

```
df['bool'] = df.apply(lambda row: all(w in row['m'] for w in v), axis=1)
count = df['bool'].sum()
```

but this was slower than the vectorisation.

Now these methods work, and the vectorisation is much faster than the initial approach, but it feels a bit clunky (creating a column with identical values, using a helper function in such a way). So my question, performance is key, **is there a better/faster way to count the number of times a list is contained in a column of lists?** Since the lists contain no duplicates, perhaps the check if `len(union(df['m'], df['V'])) == len(df['m'])` or something, but I don't know how and if that's the best solution.

Edit: Since somebody asked; here's an example with strings instead of integers:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'m': [["aa","ab","ac"], ["aa","ac","ad"], ["ba","bb"], ["ac","ca","cc"], ["aa"], ["ac","da","aa"]]})
>>> v = ["aa", "ac"]
>>> df
                    m
0  ["aa", "ab", "ac"]
1  ["aa", "ac", "ad"]
2        ["ba", "bb"]
3  ["ac", "ca", "cc"]
4              ["aa"]
5  ["ac", "da", "aa"]

>>> count_occurrence(df, v)
3
```

But if you want a more extensive DataFrame, you can generate it with this:

```
import string

n = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'m': [list(set([''.join(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:5], np.random.randint(3, 4))) for _ in range(np.random.randint(1, 10))])) for _ in range(n)]})
v = ["abc", 'cde']
print(count_occurrence(df, v))
```

Edit:
Neither Divakar's or Vaishali's solution was faster than the one that uses `np.vectorize`. Wonder if anyone can beat it.

Jon Clements came with a solution that is roughly 30% faster and much cleaner: `df.m.apply(set(v).issubset).sum()`. I continue looking for faster implementations, but this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Could you add representative sample data with strings as input too?

Comment: Done. Added a simple example and a way to generate a large DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks! Also, would it be safe to assume that the strings would always of the same number of characters, like here they are two character strings?

Comment: No the strings vary wildly in length.

Comment: I see. My posted solution here assumes generic case. Would like to hear how it performs on your actual dataset.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Will get back to you tomorrow when I'm back at work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilise `DataFrame.apply` along with the builtin `set.issubset` method and then `.sum()` which all operate at a lower level (normally C level) than Python equivalents do.

```
subset_wanted = {2, 3}
count = df.m.apply(subset_wanted.issubset).sum()
```

I can't see shaving more time off that than writing a custom C-level function which'd be the equivalent of a custom `sum` with a *check there's a subset* to determine 0/1 on a row by row basis. At which point, you could have run this thousands upon thousands of times anyway.

Comment: Got me thinking though... might be nice to have something like `count = df.m.count_if(...)` in pandas.... or possibly `count_where` sticking with naming conventions.

Comment: Unless the ``count_where`` function offers some optimization, be it speed or memory wise, I don't see a reason to add  this method to the package since as you've shown it can already be done very concisely.

Comment: @Jurgy I imagine it'd be along the same lines as how the builtin `map` / `filter` works... providing a one off reference to an equivalently low level bound function *might* work (as opposed to passing Python level or user level ufuncs). I admit to not thinking it through thoroughly. but if passed something like `str.lower`, `set(something).some_method` etc... might just work

Comment: In principle since the end result will always be a scalar, you don't need an entire Series/ndarray of the mask/boolean results to sum, so you move the computation of that into the sum/count itself - while I *have* to iterate over the series/ndarray at whatever level to get the mask returned, if I *know* I only want an aggregate value, I can compute both in that loop itself

Comment: The difference between `select count(*) from table where something..." and "select count(*) from (select 1 from something where condition=...)`

Comment: You've convinced me. If you're really confident in your idea you can implement it and create a pull-request for the pandas-dev github repo ;)

Comment: @Jurgy heck no! While I've got over 10 years of Python under my belt - and fairly au fait with its inner workings , I've only really used pandas for a couple of years and still consider myself a beginner (and never delved deep into how a lot of things work at an implementation level). Just one of those "off the top of my head" things - fairly sure the development crew would have already thought about it/dismissed it. There's a friendly crowd in [the Python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) including a few very experienced numpy/pandas people... Might be worth saying hi.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking more a set-like behavior

```
(df.m.apply(lambda x: set(x).intersection(set([2,3]))) == set([2,3])).sum()
```

Returns

```
3
```

Comment: Thanks, but according to blogs like [this one](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) looping with ``apply`` is slower than vectorization which is why I went for the aproach I mentioned. I am not at work right now, so can't check if your solution is faster. One last thing: shouldn't that last  ``set([2,3])`` after the equals operator be ``set(x)``?

Comment: Back at work; this approach is roughly 60% slower than my vectorize approach. On a dataset of 10.000 rows, my approach took 0.7 seconds and yours took 1.7 seconds.

Comment: @Jurgy what about something like `df.m.apply({2, 3}.issubset).sum()`

Comment: @Jon Clements that solution is a bit faster and much cleaner too, thank you very much! 0.40 seconds versus 0.64 seconds on the same dataset. I keep looking for faster solutions, but this is a step in the right direct.

Comment: @Jurgy I'll add it as a possible answer then? I can't think of anyway it can go faster than that though... you're using the vectorized apply (C-level) with a builtin `set` method (C-level) and then summing (C-level)... The other only way to potentially speed it up is to avoid generating the complete result of the `apply` which while avoiding the memory overhead will move the iteration back into a Python level for-loop so you lose all advantages there.

Comment: I guess you are right. You can add it as an answer.